# How to Install Swagger on Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I started to install like this:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html
Step 1.

```
`composer require nelmio/api-doc-bundle` - Thats OK
```

Step 2.

```
    class AppKernel extends Kernel
    {
        public function registerBundles()
        {
                $bundles = [
                    new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(),
                ];
        }
    }
```

But I have no AppKernel extends Kernel. I **just have Kernel** with 
`$contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';`
So I added into **/config/bundles.php**

```
Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Step 3.
I added into **config/routes.yaml**

```
# config/routes.yaml
app.swagger_ui:
    path: /api/doc
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }
```

Step 4.
I created **config/packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml** with

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        path_patterns: # an array of regexps
            - ^/api(?!/doc$)
        host_patterns:
            - ^api\.
```

After that I should see Swagger's page at mysite/api/doc
But i see only white page with link 'NelmioApiDocBundle' at github
**What I did wrong?**

Comment: Have you added annotations to your routes as written in this section?
https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html#using-the-bundle

Comment: > Have you added annotations to your routes as written in this section?
Yes
It didnt change anything
And as far as I understood, Step 3 enouth for swagger start page

Comment: In a couple of days it started to work wothout new changes.
I dont know why...

Comment: It might be that a cache in var/cache was cleared.

Comment: @RA I cleared it before a lot of times

Comment: Hey i have the same problem. How did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran:

```
bin/console assets:install --symlink
```

and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **areas** in your **nelmio_api_doc**

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: My App
            description: This is an awesome app!
            version: 1.0.0
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
            - ^/secured/project(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
```