# Swagger returns authentication required

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I followed official [documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/4.x/index.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042722/how-to-install-swagger-on-symfony-4) so I can configure Swagger on my Symfony project.

As I am in my local environment I tried to access: http://localhost:8083/api/doc to see if everything is setup.

The route renders: `{"message":"Authentication Required"}`

I configured:

- bundle in **bundles.yaml**
- routes in **routes.yaml**
- specified areas
  in **nelmio_api_doc.yaml**

My `routes.yaml` file:

```
app.swagger_ui:
 path: api/doc
  methods: GET
  defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }

app.swagger:
  path: api/doc.json
  methods: GET
  defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger }
```

Has it something to do with *security.yaml* file and how I can surpass this message?

`security.yaml` file:

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have posted a link and I did every  step described in the documentation. @GaryHoubre

Comment: Can you show your routes.yaml

Comment: Yes. I updated my post. @GaryHoubre

Comment: Can you show your security.yaml, access_control part (file into config/package)

Comment: And can you help me with the idea: I think api doc should not be accessible from the application. It should somehow be generated statically in the project itself, that we can access it from there. Is that possible? @GaryHoubre

Comment: start simple by removing the access control completely, so you know that swagger was correctly installed.

Comment: I have checked, when I remove api prefix everything loads so the problem is with that prefix. @TimZwinkels